# Start java in windows batch and kill it when timeout, need output java console to a file

Tags: windows, batch-file, output, nonblocking

In my batch script, I need to run java automation and kill the java process when timeout.

1. run java
2. loop to verify if java process exist, if still running during timeout then kill the process.

When I use start java, then the java execution won't output to the console file.

```
start java -Xms64m -Xmx1024m -cp my.jar 2>&1 >Console.txt
```

When I remove start, the console could be generated but it will pending at java command, it will not execute to the verify after.

```
java -Xms64m -Xmx1024m -cp my.jar 2>&1 >Console.txt
```

Comment: how about specifying the full path to the file, so at least you know where it is? `> "C:\my path\to\console.txt`

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply! The console.txt could be generated, but it's 0KB, no content in it. Anyway I tried with the full path, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share I use another workaround to realize. What I am using is jenkins job, I use parallel step to get it worked. One job in parallel is to execute "java -Xms64m -Xmx1024m -cp my.jar 2>&1 >Console.txt", the other job is to execute "verify if java pid still running, if running then loop wait, when timeout, kill the pid".